# Create a contact page in oracle rightnow customer portal

Tags: rightnow-crm

I am new to oracle right now. I am trying to create contact page . 
How to create the **contact** page ?
How to create **incident** page ?

Answer (score 0):

In the reference implementation oracle gives you basic pages which can be customized. You can visit your portal pages by going through pages using cyberduck or other webdav software. For read view you can visit https:///dav/cp/customer/development/pages in browser.